# Zsh completion: How to find the function that is used for completions with a specific command?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I am writing a zsh completion function for a shell script/program I wrote. At some point in the completion process I want to use the completion function of another command to handle the rest of the completion.

**How can I find out what the completion function for a specific command is called?  How can I look up the existing `compdef` assignments in my shell?**

#### Background

My program wraps `nvim` and there is no `_nvim` function in my shell which I would have guessed would be the completion function. So I assume the completion function that `nvim` uses is actually `_vim` but this question is more general in order to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type the command plus a space and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>H</kbd> to the run the [`_complete_help` widget](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fcomplete_005fhelp-_0028_005eXh_0029). For example:

```
% nvim # press ^Xh here
tags in context :completion::complete:nvim::
    argument-rest options  (_arguments _vim)
tags in context :completion::complete:nvim:argument-rest:
    globbed-files  (_files _vim_files _arguments _vim)
```

This tells you that for arguments to command `nvim` , the completion system will call `_vim`, which then calls `_arguments`, which adds `argument-rest` and `options` completions. Then, `_arguments` calls `_vim_files`, which calls `_files`, which adds `globbed-files` completions.

Alternatively, if you're interested in only the top-level completion function set for a particular command, do this:

```
% print $_comps[nvim]
_vim
```